# Cantilever beam with a mass at different positions and resonance frequency

Tags: resonance, structural-beam

I have a Cantilever beam attached to vibration generator at the bottom. I have a piece of blu tac of some mass and I move it down the ruler. Whilst moving it down I notice the resonance frequency of the ruler reduces at a linear rate with respect to the rulers overall center of gravity. Is there a maths relationship behind this or a physics principle that can help me explain this? The values are in cm for the first 2 columns and hz for the third. The first 2 columns are distances from the base/pivot (where the generator is attached).

[image]

Comment: What does it look like in numbers?

Comment: There is, and it can be solved for.

Comment: Ive added the data I recorded

Comment: You have already asked this question. If you want to attract more answers to the other question you can make any edit to your other question. This will return your question to the top of the home page.

Comment: My setup is not a pendulum, why can it still be modelled this way?